# Which chat method is good gcm or Quickblox?

Tags: android, xampp

I am trying to develop a chat application. When l search, l am able to know that using gcm and Quickblox are main method. In this which one is good and easy? Or is there is any other method please help me
i need push notification in chat and all the chat on my server

Answer (score 0):

Other than this i found a new code 
this is very simple

[simple-android-instant-messaging-application](https://code.google.com/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/)